# MEF function on getexport (non-singleton)

Tags: mef

I need to do the following in MEF:

Whenever I resolve a certain interface I need a piece of code to run which gives the implementation.

It must never be a singleton, so MEF must always run that particular piece of code.

private IContract MethodToExecute()

var resolved = container.GetExport(); --> must run the MethodToExecute

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use Lazy<IContract>, and put whatever code you need to run in the constructor of the exported part? I'm not sure I understand what you need to do.

Comment: I have a third party contract and a third party implementation of the contract. The implementation accepts constructor arguments. I want to use the contract and the existing implementation. I don't want to create a new class inheriting from the existing implementation.

Comment: Has the third party marked the constructor with the `ImportingConstructor` attribute? You should be able to tell by looking at the composition and seeing if there are parts that correspond to the constructor's parameters.